# Login timeout expired while connecting to SQL Server using workload identity

Tags: azure, kubernetes, pyodbc, azure-managed-identity

I am following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=sqldatabase%2Cuserassigned%2Cpython%2Cwindowsclient) from Microsoft.

```
import pyodbc

connString = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER=tcp:<server-name>.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=<db-name>;ConnectionTimeout=60;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi"

conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
```

Above code giving me this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I want to highlight that I have verified that all permissions are correctly set for the workload identity used in the Kubernetes namespace. Additionally, when I change the connection string to use a UID and password, it works without any issues.

Can anyone help me identify and resolve this problem when connecting to SQL Server using Managed Identity within a Kubernetes pod?

I have tried this code -

```
import pyodbc

connString = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER=tcp:<server-name>.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=<db-name>;ConnectionTimeout=60;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi"

conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
```

It should be able to connect to sql server.

Comment: Can you check with version of `azure.identity` your are using ? only lastest versions support workload identity.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to replicate the issue with the provided code, I got a similar error as shown below:

[image]

I tried the following code to connect to SQL Server using Managed Identity within a Kubernetes pod:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import pyodbc, struct

# Uncomment one of the two lines depending on the identity type
credential = DefaultAzureCredential() # system-assigned identity
#credential = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id='<client-id-of-user-assigned-identity>') # user-assigned identity

# Get token for Azure SQL Database and convert to UTF-16-LE for SQL Server driver
token = credential.get_token("https://database.windows.net/.default").token.encode("UTF-16-LE")
token_struct = struct.pack(f'<I{len(token)}s', len(token), token)

# Connect with the token
SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
connString = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER=dbservere.database.windows.net;DATABASE=db"
conn = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: token_struct})
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

It connected successfully as shown below:

[image]

Additionally, as @Thomas mentioned, check your `azure.identity` version, as only the latest version supports workload identity. For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76782234/managed-identity-to-connect-aks-with-azure-sql).